# Transparency dithering issue when saving for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, optimization

I am trying to optimize the graphics for a webdesign, since I am not satisfied with the performance in terms of load-times. The logo is quite big and in PNG24 so I experimented to see how much I could shrink it. It was thrilled to see that I could get from 158KB to 61KB with practically no image quality loss until I started implementing the picture in the design and noticed white "ghosting" transparency issues around some of the edges. Then I started playing around with transparency dithering, but the best result I managed to get was with diffusion dithering enabled, but the amount set to 0% (yeah, it actually still has an effect?!), but I still find the edges a bit to jagged for what I am looking for. I made a collage where I put the tree versions of the logo on a subtle gradient, which makes it easier to see the issues on the following link:

[image: images]

Any suggestions on how I can get closer to that attractive ≈ 60KB filesize without giving up on the smooth edges when not performing dithering?

BTW: I'm using the "save for web" dialogue in Photoshop CS5.5 in case you're wondering.

Comment: There seems to be quite a lot of scum around the edges if there is that much dithering going on in the first image. May be a silly question, but have you verified it's a clean edged image?

Comment: It looks really clean up close. I just tried disabling the layers - suspected that the textures might interfere with the edges - but I had the same issues when trying to export.

Comment: have you considered a JPG?

Comment: What is the final background that this will sit on? Knowing this will help with suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

1.) In PhotoShop, Save For Web and save as a 24-bit transparent PNG.

2.) Use a third party to compress the image. I like https://tinypng.com/

3.) Your image was compressed down to your target 60kb with lossy compression preserving full alpha transparency. No white edges, no image quality loss.

Answer (score 1):

I know you didnt say this but why wouldn't you just code everything in CSS if you are worried about load times and file sizes?

- [Circles](http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles) tutorial, David's [demo](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-circles.php) and another good [tutorial](http://bryanhadaway.com/how-to-create-circles-with-css/) by Brian Hadaway
- Angled text [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/)

**EDIT:**
Other circular questions on the stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-css-a-number-to-be-surrounded-by-a-circle)

Comment: I considered doing that and plan to do it for simpler elements on the site, but with all the textures and shadowing going on I don't think I will get a good enough result for the logo. I'm also planning to provide a fallback of the site for non-CSS3 browsers and I would need the logo there, although I would probably simplify the rest of the design a lot.

Comment: Have you considered then separating each area?  Code the circle with CSS but use a background image for the effect?  Also have you considered an option to file size optimization such as http://punypng.com/

Answer (score 1):

I did some playing with the image... extracted a copy from your PNG24 example and tried several methods. In the end I'd use this, myself:

[image: with matte]

(not great on white.. better on a grey)

What I did was use PNG8 with no color diffusion, then set the transparency diffusion to 50% dithered, and added a grey matte color (#dddddd). That slight grey matte helps the edges look clean on a wide range of greys even if they don't match the specific matte color. You can play with various CSS background colors using [this jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/arnpE/1/). You'll see it seems to work well on a range of lighter grey backgrounds. It seems to start failing once you pass #999 for the page color.

It is far from the smooth edge of a PNG24. But there's no way to get the PNG24 smooth edge in an indexed color image (PNG8) So it's a trade off... **which is more important the smooth transparency or the file size?** And granted I'm working from an extracted copy of the image. Your results may be better with original files.

Comment: I have heard rumours that png8 supports alpha transparency, but has imperfect browser support and Photoshop does not export it.